# Is there a more efficient way to apply a recursive function to a column in a DataFrame than a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the DataFrame:

```
import numpy
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})

    a
0   1.0 
1   1.0
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
5   NaN
6   NaN
```

And I want to fill the NaNs with the values of the Fibonacci series (or any other recursive function):

```
    a
0   1.0 
1   1.0
2   2.0
3   3.0
4   5.0
5   8.0
6   13.0
```

Clearly, I can do this using a for loop:

```
for i in range(2, len(df)):
    df.loc[i, 'a'] = df.loc[i-1, 'a'] + df.loc[i-2, 'a']
```

Is there a built-in method in pandas, or any other way to avoid iterating through the table, to make this more efficient?

Comment: What "inefficiency" are you trying to remove?  If you want to assign to each row of the table, you're going to have to iterate over it.

Comment: In terms of iterations, I think no. But you can do [computation by rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Computation_by_rounding).

Comment: Let's say your built-in panda's method does exist. If it is updating every value in your dataframe, somewhere under the hood it must be accessing all of those locations in memory, right? I do not understand how this is any different/less efficient than iteration.

Comment: You can use `apply` instead of a standard for loop or `iterrows()`.  See the discussing [here](https://realpython.com/fast-flexible-pandas/#pandas-apply).